# get json data from php file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've already looked all answers about this and it is not helping me. I'm trying to get json data from PHP file. It's working but I can't output all data.

The array that I get from PHP file looks like this:

```
connected<pre>Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CategoryID] => 1
        [CategoryName] => Beverages
        [Description] => Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales
        [Picture] => beverages.gif
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CategoryID] => 2
        [CategoryName] => Condiments
        [Description] => Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings
        [Picture] => condiments.gif
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [CategoryID] => 3
        [CategoryName] => Confections
        [Description] => Desserts, candies, and sweet breads
        [Picture] => confections.gif
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [CategoryID] => 4
        [CategoryName] => Dairy Products
        [Description] => Cheeses
        [Picture] => diary.gif
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [CategoryID] => 5
        [CategoryName] => Grains/Cereals
        [Description] => Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal
        [Picture] => cereals.gif
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [CategoryID] => 6
        [CategoryName] => Meat/Poultry
        [Description] => Prepared meats
        [Picture] => meat.gif
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [CategoryID] => 7
        [CategoryName] => Produce
        [Description] => Dried fruit and bean curd
        [Picture] => produce.gif
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [CategoryID] => 8
        [CategoryName] => Seafood
        [Description] => Seaweed and fish
        [Picture] => seafood.gif
    )

 )
 </pre>
```

and my Ajax function looks like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"data.php",
    type:"json",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data)
        $.each(data, function(key, field){
            $("container").append(field.CategoryName)
        })
    }
});
```

I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1678' in connectedArray

Comment: use: 
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
 $("container").append(data[i].CategoryName)
}

Comment: If your PHP code is actually sending `connected<pre>` and `</pre>` that's part of your problem. Find out where those are being added and remove them. Also, make sure that you `json_encode` your array.

Comment: Have you convert php array to Json?

Comment: What is your PHP code that generates that?

Comment: @viktorino Please show your PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data.php`should look similar to this.

```
$arData = array(

    [0]=>array(

        'categoryID' => 1,
        'categoryName' => 'Beverages',
        'description' => 'oft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales',
        'picture' => 'beverages.gif'      

    )

);

$jsonData = json_encode( $arData );
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
print( $jsonData );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your PHP output, it's not valid JSON because you've got the word "connected" and HTML tags in there - strip them out, and encode everything with json_encode

then add

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

to the top of your file.